# How to extract hour from the time

Tags: python, split

I have a text file (in an email format) that I need to extract out the hours (in HH:MM:SS format). I initially split the text but can't seem to split the results again to grab the time only.  If I do manage to isolate the time and try again, it provides me with

```py
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'"
```

Text Sample

```py
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
```

Here is my code

```
name = input('Enter File:')
input to default to mbox-short.txt
if len(name) < 1 : name = 'mbox-short.txt'
handle = open(name)

counts = dict()
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('From '):
        words = line.split()
        time = words[5:6]
        print(time)
        hour = time.split(':')
        print(hour)
```

The eventual goal is to build a histogram/time-series - any insights would be helpful to get past this part so I can continue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the result of string.split() is list.  You need to pull the string that you want out of the list and then split that.

```
handle=['From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008']
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith('From '):
        words = line.split()
        
        # time = words[5:6]
        # time=time[0] # extract the string

        # this is better than extracting yet another sub list though
        time = words[5]

        print(time)
        hour = time.split(':')
        print(hour)
```

output:

```
09:14:16
['09', '14', '16']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
time = words[5:6]
```

You are going to get a list back. Any time you get a "slice" of a list like this, it returns another list. So time is a list.
You could "unpack" the list (which will always have just one element) like this:

```
[time] = words[5:6]
```

and then your code will work.

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before.  You learn something new every day.

Comment: today I learned that there's many ways to tackle the same problem, even in the coding world.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You are slicing a sequence (`words[5:6]`) and it will give you a sub-sequence, i.e. a shorter sequence of the same type as the original one. What you need to do get the element at position 5 is to use indexing notation: `words[5]` -- this will give you the element at that position alone.

Answer (score 0):

May I introduce you to [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), or **regex**.  This is a **very** useful sub-language used for text pattern matching - perfect for your hour extraction example.

Here is a link to an excellent [online tool](https://regexr.com/) for testing/learning patterns.

#### For example:

Text string: `From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008`

From your text string above you can write the pattern: `(\d{2}):\d{2}:\d{2}` to extract the hours.  With the output being: `09`.

#### Breakdown:

- The `()` creates a 'capture group'; the set of values you want to extract.
- `\d` matches any character which is a digit
- `{2}` matches 2 of the previous tokens, in this case, a digit
- `:` matches the literal ':' character

String it all together and you can match the time pattern of `(2digits):2digits:2digits` with the first set of `2digits` being extracted.

#### In Python:

```
import re

text = 'From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008'
exp = r'(\d{2}):\d{2}:\d{2}'

# Search for the pattern in the text string.
m = re.search(exp, text)
# Extract and print the first match (0 index) from the matches found.
print(m.groups()[0])
```

#### Output:

`09`